# Would this feature "fix" Christianity SE or make it more confusing?

Tags: feature-request, tags, discussion

Looks like there's some notion of "versioning" that is going to be added to the technical sites

[Version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers?cb=1)

I added Christianity to the wiki answer on that post with some ideas for how we might use it.  I'm not sure they're ever going to extend the functionality to us (since it might be a round peg for a square hole).

Do you think it could help or hurt the site to have tags for answers in addition to questions (not versions, versions don't make much sense, until Vatican III at least)

Comment: Probably not useful for here. Our scoping rules are already quite tight.

Answer (score 1):

Curiousdannii's right in commenting that our scoping rules are already quite tight, but to say that it would probably not be useful here is what I'm getting at.

If we *could* tag answers, then we could loosen up the scoping rules and allow general questions a chance to thrive without the necessity of attempting to write boneheaded answers to things we don't know beans about (which is what I do whenever I attempt to answer an overview question).

If we did this, I'd be in favor of organizing a posse to unclose some of the oldest and most egregious violators of our closing policy.  I'd even go so far as to close the old "Brothers, we are not Christians" post on meta in favor of another post composed entirely of musical lyrics.  This is the feature we've been looking for, through artful ignorance of tags which we do not care for, we can boldly return to ignoring one another's differences!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this feature can be useful for some types of questions such as basic level questions to which I propose a use case scenario [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7189/10672).

And yes, with carefully prescribed policies and minor question editing, this can unclose some past basic level questions.